# react-select Not Showing default selected values as selected in search list

Tags: reactjs, react-select

**Package:** "react-select": "^4.3.1", "react": "^17.0.2"
**Issue:** Multi SELECT tag in react-select library.
When item is manually selected, they appear properly as selected. But Default passed values are not shown as selected.

Code as follows:-
*NOTE:-* No compilation errors or any other errors appears.

In case any more details needed, please do let me know.

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';
      import Select from 'react-select';

      export const MainForm = ({ Associate, selectedOptionValues, specializationMaster, 
      notifySelectChange }) => {

    let defaultValues = [];

    if (Array.isArray(specializationMaster) && Array.isArray(Associate.SpecializationIds)) {
        if (specializationMaster.length > 1) {
            defaultValues = Associate.SpecializationIds.map(item => item._id);
        }
    }
    console.log("defaultValues", defaultValues);

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="SpecializationIds2"><h6>Specializations:</h6>
            </label>
            <Select
                name="SpecializationIds"
                options={specializationMaster}
                defaultValues={defaultValues}
                getOptionLabel={x => x.SpecializationName}
                getOptionValue={x => x._id}
                onChange={notifySelectChange}
                isMulti={true}
            />
        </div>
         )
         }

         export const MainScreen = () => {
         const [specializationMaster] = useState([
        {
            "_id": "60d0965a6f43b55730730935",
            "SpecializationName": "ASP.Net"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60d0965a6f43b55730730934",
            "SpecializationName": "Angular"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60d0965a6f43b55730730937",
            "SpecializationName": "Knockout"
        }
    ]);
    const [currentAssociate, setCurrentAssociate] = useState({
        SpecializationIds: [{
            "_id": "60d0965a6f43b55730730934",
            "SpecializationName": "Angular"
        }]
    });
    const notifySelectChange = (selectedOption) => {
        let specializationIds = [];
        if (selectedOption && selectedOption.length > 0) {
            specializationIds = selectedOption.map(specItem => ({ ...specItem }));
        }
        setCurrentAssociate({ ...currentAssociate, SpecializationIds: specializationIds });
    };

    return (
        <MainForm Associate={currentAssociate}
            selectedOptionValues={currentAssociate.SpecializationIds}
            specializationMaster={specializationMaster}
            notifySelectChange={notifySelectChange}
        />
         );
}```
````